# Laravel Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project in server it works fine but when i cloned that project and try to run on my local it shows this error in my consolse. I cannot navigate to other pages as well. When i try to navigate it shows ***This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 unexpectedly closed the connection.***

Comment: Did you check if your `.htaccess` is properly written to enable the routing?

Comment: @Lenin htaccess seems to be fine

Comment: If you are using Homestead, make sure to restart and re-provision the box.

Comment: I fixed this issue because project was forcefully redirecting it to the HTTPS. While i am in local. in Appservice provider

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to AppServiceProvider
2. comment URL::forceScheme('https');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).